# Error in serialization when consuming JSON Objects from Kafka

Tags: json, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to produce Json Objects to Kafka and consume them manually, I am using the JSONPOJO Serdes in org.apache.kafka.streams.examples.pageview.

My producer code is :

```
package JsonProducer;

imports ...

public class jsnPdc {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        byte[] arr= "XXXX       THIS IS TEST DATA \n XYZ".getBytes();    
        JSONObject jsn = new JSONObject();
        jsn.put("Header_Title", (Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, 4)));
        jsn.put("Data_Part", (Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 4, arr.length)));


        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxx");
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.streams.examples.pageview.JsonPOJOSerializer");

        KafkaProducer<String, JSONObject> pdc = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
        pdc.send(new ProducerRecord<String,JSONObject>("testoutput", jsn));

        System.in.read();


    }

}
```

and the code for consumer is :

```
package testConsumer;

imports ...

public class consumer_0 {
    static public void main(String[] argv) throws ParseException {

        //Configuration
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxx");
        props.put("group.id", "test");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.streams.examples.pageview.JsonPOJODeserializer");


        //Create Consumer Object
        KafkaConsumer<String, JSONObject> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, JSONObject>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("testoutput"));


        //Keep Polling Records
        System.out.println("Polling new record...\n");
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, JSONObject> records = consumer.poll(100);

            //Print Each Record
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, JSONObject> record : records){
                JSONObject json = record.value();

                //Some print code, print(json) ...

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition testoutput-0 at offset 20491
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Type: [null]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Type: [null]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1170)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructType(TypeFactory.java:618)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2929)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.examples.pageview.JsonPOJODeserializer.deserialize(JsonPOJODeserializer.java:49)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:882)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseCompletedFetch(Fetcher.java:788)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:480)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1061)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:995)
    at testConsumer.consumer_0.main(consumer_0.java:43)
```

I need the value field type of json to be in byte array. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood whose responsibility it is to serialize the values. You're telling Kafka to serialize the values you give it using `org.apache.kafka.streams.examples.pageview.JsonPOJOSerializer`, which is expecting a plain java object, something like

```
class Data {
    private String headerTitle;
    private String dataPart;
    //... constructors, getters, setters
}
```

But you have actually passed a `JSONObject` to the `ProducerRecord`  (in other words, you've already serialized the data yourself before you give it to Kafka which then gamely tries to serialize it *again*).

You can either serialize your `jsn` vale yourself, but using the `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer` as your `value.serializer`, or you can strick with unsing the `org.apache.kafka.streams.examples.pageview.JsonPOJOSerializer` and define a class like `Data` above and pass an interance of that class to the `ProducerRecord`.

Comment: Thanks! Now I finally understand what was going on but I already fixed this issue by serializing my entire jsn object as byte[] then deserialize it on my consumer side as byte[]. Both using "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerde". Do you think this can effect the performance of my streaming/consuming compare to using POJO and JsonPOJOSerde?

Comment: If you're dealing with a complex tree of data then POJO would make for more easily understood code. I would guess that using the jsn route would be more efficient (because the Jackson `ObjectMapper` works via reflection), but if performance is an important requirement then you should profile which is faster.